# Automatically adding email addresses from Form to Contact Group

Tags: forms, email, google-drive-api, google-contacts-api

I am in charge of an upcoming student conference and have created a registration form on Google Drive where one of the 'questions' asked was of the email address of the registrant. In Google Drive all the email addresses are collated in one column.

Is there a way to automatically sync this column of email addresses to a specified Contact Group so that every other registrant's email address will be updated in the group? This will help facilitate my responding to them on updates of the conference.

Thank you very much for your help :)